# How to enable my VPS for SSH remote connections?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I got a new Hostinger VPS today running `Ubuntu`. I'm a PHP developer but a total noob with linux scripting and I'm unable to connect to my VPS over SSH. Their tech support tells me I'm on my own.

I'm on Win11 and I'm trying both Putty and Windows command prompt, but the problem isn't on the client side. I have (temporarily) disabled my windows firewall just to rule that out as a problem. Even the Hostinger support guy confirmed that he also cannot SSH into my VPS.

First I try root:

```
ssh root@0.0.0.0
```

(I'm obviously obscuring the real IP.)

Response: `ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection timed out`

So I figure that root may be disabled from connecting over SSH and I set up an SSH user in my `hpanel`:

[image]

Then I try to connect with that user:

```
ssh n*****@0.0.0.0
```

Response: `ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection timed out`

I *can* connect to my terminal via this really slow and crappy web client provided by Hostinger, and I ran:

```
ufw status
```

Result:

[image]

What do I need to do so that I can connect remotely via SSH to my VPS? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `ufw allow 22` and that solved it.